# What determines the initial value of an item in a C array when not given an explicit value?

Tags: c

I've been curious about the values that initialized variables take on when not given an explicit value in C. Some things makes a lot of sense, such as when an integer i is initialized, it will automatically be assigned 0. The value of c[0] also makes sense to me. When I try running this code, I get a whole host of variables for c[0] from run to run, such as 35, -48, 119, and -110. This corresponds to what you'd expect out of a randomly picked signed 1-byte number. (between -127 to 127)

However, the results for c[1] and c[2] don't make sense to me. Whenever I run this, c[1] is always somewhere between -1 and -4, and c[2] is always 127. Why is it like this? I'd expect it to just be junk bytes like c[0], and similarly  be a random number between -127 and 127. I am running Ubuntu Mate and using GCC to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;

int main()
{
char  c[5];

printf("%d\n", i);
printf("%d\n", c[0]);
printf("%d\n", c[1]);
printf("%d\n", c[2]);
}
```

Comment: The values of uninitialized local variables are indeterminate.

Comment: "when an integer i is initialized, it will automatically be assigned 0." - huh? When you initialize an integer, it gets the value of the initializer you provide

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I understand that, but what I find interesting is that they are showing certain patterns that you wouldn't expect out of something truly indeterminate. For example, c[2] always being 127.

Comment: The problem here lies solely with your expectation

Comment: If you really want to know why you get what you do, you can read the generated assembly code, see what memory location is being accessed, and then trace backward in your program to see what value was last stored there.  One can waste an unlimited amount of time on such meaningless exercises, and of course as soon as you change the code or the compiler flags at all, it may become completely different.

Comment: The compiler takes no special pains to make the value actually random (as that would be a waste of time and computrons), so you will tend to observe patterns, just because the surrounding code usually has some kind of structure and works with data that isn't totally random itself.  But again, there is no particular value in trying to figure out exactly why a particular value appeared. (Just noticed the pun, it was completely accidental...)

Answer (score 1):

Any variable that is global, static or thread-local will have its initialized value or zero.

However, all other variables are automatic. In almost all current C implementations that means they are on the stack or placed into a CPU register.

Also as pointed out, the compiler can optimize an undefined value into anything it wants. It can write `if` or `while` comparisons assuming they are always true or always false. Since the variable could be anything, the optimizer assumes whatever is most convenient.

Check out this example: https://godbolt.org/z/WGe6dv
You can see the optimizer skips the loop because `x` is assumed to be false. But if you change the `-O2` option to `-O0` it is reading from `[rbp-4]` which is a stack slot.

Unless the variable declaration also has an assignment, an automatic variable will hold whatever value its register or stack had before. That might be the local variables from a previous function call, or it might be part of a calculation that used it for temporary storage.

This cannot be used for anything serious. It will change from different compile options, different versions of the compiler, slightly different code, etc. Or on some C implementations there may not even be a stack.

Comment: Re “an automatic variable will hold whatever value its register or stack had before”: This is not correct. An uninitialized object may behave as if it does not hold any specific value; it may behave as if it has different values at different times. This arises from the C rules because C 3.19.2 says an indeterminate values is either an unspecified value or a trap representation and 3.19.13 says, for an unspecified value, “this document imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in **any instance**,” and it arises in practice when optimization removes loads that were found to be unneeded.

Comment: E.g., given `printf("%d", x); printf("%d", x);`, if `x` were initialized, the compiler might generate “load string address, load x, call printf, load string address, load x, call printf,” and the same value would be printed twice. But, if `x` is uninitialized, the optimizer may remove “load x,” resulting in “load string address, call printf, load string address, call printf,” but the first printf changes whatever value is in the register where `x` would be passed, so a different value is printed in the second call.

Comment: Re “all other variables are automatic”: Or thread local.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah the compiler optimization might do freaky things with it. But in general when looking at the machine code or in a debugger, it'll be reading from an assigned register or stack memory location.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple term for these values -- **Garbage Values**. They are **not** truly random, and are almost *certainly* generated on the basis of *some* patter/logic, but this is least interesting, since trying to `printf()` a garbage value is **nearly always** a mistake.

As pointed out in the comments, if you are *seriously interested* in finding out he aforementioned pattern/logic for the value, you will have to go through the generated assembly and be able to comprehend it.